# Play 2.3.x: Non-blocking image upload to Amazon S3

Tags: java, playframework, amazon-s3, playframework-2.0

I am wondering what the correct way with Play 2.3.x (Java) is to upload images to Amazon S3 in a non-blocking way.
Right now I am wrapping the amazons3.putObject method inside a promise. However I fear that I am basically just blocking another thread with this logic. My code looks like following:

```
return Promise.promise(
        new Function0<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply() {
                if (S3Plugin.amazonS3 != null) {
                    try {
                        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
S3Plugin.s3Bucket, name + "." + format, file.getFile());
                        ObjectMetadata metadata = putObjectRequest.getMetadata();
                        if(metadata == null) {
                            metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                        }
                        metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());
                        putObjectRequest.setMetadata(metadata);
                        putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
                        S3Plugin.amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
                        return true;
                    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                        // error uploading image to s3
                        Logger.error("AmazonServiceException: " + e.toString());
                    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
                        // error uploading image to s3
                        Logger.error("AmazonClientException: " + e.toString());
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
```

What is the best way to do the upload process non-blocking?
The Amazon library also provides the TransferManager.class for asynchronous uploads but I am not sure how to utilize this in a non-blocking way either...

**SOLUTION:**
After spending quite a while figuring out how to utilize the Promise/Future in Java, I came up with following solution thanks to Will Sargent:

```
import akka.dispatch.Futures;

final scala.concurrent.Promise<Boolean> promise = Futures.promise();
... create AmazonS3 upload object ...
upload.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
        if(progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE) {
            promise.success(true);
        }
        else if(progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.FAILED_EVENT_CODE) {
            promise.success(false);
        }
    }
});
return Promise.wrap(promise.future());
```

Important to note is that I have to use the scala promise and not the play framework promise. The return value however is a play.libs.F.Promise.

Comment: At the end of the day you're going to block a thread when doing I/O, no getting around that. The code above will block a thread in Play's default thread pool, how bad that is depends largely on how big the files you are uploading (i.e. how long it will block) and how much traffic your app gets (in case you run out of threads). There are a few solutions, which I mentioned [in this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24402441/2408961), however, using AWS's `TransferManager` looks promising as you can just register a callback listener and let it manage threading etc. Never used it myself though...

Comment: But to use the callback in a correct way, I have to somehow defer the promise without blocking the thread as long as I wait for the callback. How is this possible with F.Promise?

Comment: You don't defer the promise, you return the promise's future.  See answer for details.

Comment: My answer to a similar question might give you some ideas on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535826/play-framework-async-processing-and-blocking-i-o-in-java/22761239#22761239

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I went with the solution stated above which attempts to do the procedure non-blocking rather than using a different thread-pool. Still, your link is quite helpful since I want to outsource some CPU intense calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the upload process and return a Future by creating a Promise, returning the promise's future, and only writing to the promise in the TransferManager's progress listener:

Examples of promises / futures: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Return the Scala future from Promise: [http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#wrapped()](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#wrapped%28%29)

TransferManager docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I am trying to figure out the implementation of the procedure you proposed. However I have a hard time understanding how to put this together in Java. For example: what logic goes into the apply method within the Function0.class of the F.Promise? The example link with an explanation in Scala is hard to follow since I've never done anything in Scala. Unfortunately, there is also no example with Futures on the official Play website.
Could you elaborate more on how to do it in Java?

Comment: So, promises are a way to work around the problem that callbacks like "onComplete" don't return values.  When the onComplete callback is run, the value from the computation is something you can write to the Promise, and then the future attached to the Promise will contain the value as well.  So you create a promise, you hand the Promise's future out publically so everything can read from the future, but you only write to the Promise once, in the onComplete callback.

Comment: I came up with a solution and edited my initial post. It would be very helpful for others to also explain this mechanism in the play java docs with example code as it is very confusing when to use which promise.

Comment: @JonasH you can add this to the Play java docs at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/javaGuide/main/async/JavaAsync.md -- that's how most of the documentation gets written.